# How to add working form in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to integrate a form in wordpress will anybody suggest me a plugin??

Answer (score 7):

You can check plugin in LINK URL :-
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/

I will prefer to use this as i used it before its awesome plugin for form integration..

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/

Comment: my own form i want to store input data in database

Comment: My own HTML & PHP to manage data and store it in database